# Force CMAKE to use given library and nothing else

Tags: cmake

### Position of the problem

I'm trying to force cmake to use one particular library. I want the executable to be linked statically with this one and no other. I want the build to fail if it can't link both "libgpg-error.a" and "libgcrypt.a" statically from the "/XXX/static_libs" directory.

### What I have so far:

So far, my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
# Project Setup
project(file_crypt)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

# Includes
include_directories(.)

# Link
link_directories( ${gcrypt_lib_dir} ${dl_crypt_lib_dir} )
find_library( gcrypt_libs NAMES libgcrypt.a libgpg-error.a PATHS ${gcrypt_lib_dir} NO_DEFAULT_PATH )

# Executables Declarations
add_executable( my_decrypt
                my_decrypt.cpp [...] )
set_target_properties( my_decrypt PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32" )


# Link to libraries
target_link_libraries( my_decrypt ${gcrypt_libs} dl crypt )
```

I added:

```
gcrypt_lib_dir:FILEPATH=/XXX/static_libs
```

to my *CMakeCache.txt*. And if I do *"ls"* on *"/XXX/static_libs"*, I can see both "libgpg-error.a" and "libgcrypt.a".

Then I run cmake. **Then gcrypt_libs variable is set to not found**

### Questions

1. Why would cmake not find those libs ?
2. is The above file correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set `gcrypt_libs` in your CMakeLists.txt rather than in CMakeCache.txt, which is an autogenerated file. I believe if you use the [set](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html) command to set the variable, it should work. Add a line like:

```
set( gcrypt_libs /XXX/static_libs )
```

right before your call to `find_library` and it should work.

**Update:** As mentioned in your comment, `/XXX/static_libs` is a machine-dependent location and shouldn't be hardcoded into CMakeLists.txt. Your idea to initialize variables with `cmake -C <initial-cache>` should work perfectly -- the only thing is, as cmake's manpage points out: "The given file should be a CMake script containing SET commands that use the CACHE  option, not a cache-format file."

So say you keep an initial cache file called `paths.txt`, it could have

```
set( gcrypt_libs /XXX/static_libs CACHE FILEPATH "" )
```

Then you can configure with cmake in the usual way:

```
cmake -C path/to/paths.txt path/to/source
```

So basically, you still don't touch CMakeCache.txt but write a script to load values into the cache like so.

Comment: maybe i should have written it. /XXX/static_libs is dependent on the developper machine. It hence can't be in CMakeLists. Also, unless you delete the file, running cmake will preserve your CMakeCache user settings. I was more thinking of something like "-C <initial-cache>" option every developper/machine would have its own.

But +1 anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my answer to account for this information, please see if it works out.

Comment: I was sure I had tried that, but I used a small "c" , it is working. Thanks to you.